# Ruby on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Yesterday I installed ruby and rails using rvm in ubuntu 12.04 and it is working fine and also created a sample application.But today when i run

ruby -v

it is showing like

The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:

- ruby1.8
- ruby1.9.1

Try: apt-get install

Comment: you likely didn't install or configure RVM correctly. Have you added RVM to your .bashrc (or .bash_profile or whatever it tells you)?

Comment: @sevenseacat, I thought RVM was Redhat crap.

Comment: @ravi, make sure you use the most recent release, it should come with Ruby 2.x. Ruby 1.9.x is already obsolete.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky nope, rvm is a Ruby Version Manager :)

Comment: @sevenseacat, oh really, of course it is. Debian-based distros do not work well with RVM. I'm on Debian myself and I went for the standard deb package. RVM is either too pro or not very compatible with Debian-based distros.

Comment: My .bash_profile is

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function

Comment: @BorisStitnicky rvm works just fine with Debian-based distros, if you install and configure it correctly :)

Comment: I installed ruby 2.x and rails 4.1.4 using rvm but now when i give ruby -v it ishowing the above error which i posted

Comment: that's one part of the incompatibility issues that I encountered. Or maybe it was my own fault for being too stupid for RVM, as @sevenseacat suggests. But I run into a real trouble when trying to install gems with third party libraries. Or something like that, I don't remember it that well anymore. But the end result was that I abandoned RVM and went for the standard *.deb solution. And now I started compiling Ruby from source, and it somehow still works. I'm just a user, so if it ain't broken I avoid fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot the latest step when installing RVM. It is mentioned at the end of the install process but easily overlooked. It boils down to this:

Make sure you have the following lines at the bottom of `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This will load RVM right after you open a new shell. Without it, RVM is not 'activated' and when you type `ruby` it will use the version installed through your OS package manager and not the version installed through RVM.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `rvm list`. If it shows rubies then everything is ok and go to step 2.(if any problems then try reinstall rvm)(if it shows empty rubies list, then install ruby using rvm again(`rvm install 2.1.1`)
2. Specify current rvm ruby by one of the following ways:

   1. Specify ruby version manually by running `rvm use 2.1.1` for ruby2.1.1. This way you have to call this command every time you open a terminal (see next ways if this doesn't suit you)
   2. Set default ruby version. See [here](https://rvm.io/rubies/default).
   3. Use `.rvmrc` file in any directory(see [here](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc) how) to make rvm change ruby version when you open this directory.

Probably that is your case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to zwipple's answer, if you can also load rvm for once using following command:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
ruby -v 
=> #your ruby version
```